# CISCO : vtp server and client

Tags: cisco, vlan

I was doing some cisco exercises on configuring a vtp server and client, something I can't figure out is :

- I setup a vtp server, added my VLAN's
- I then took another switch that was attached to this vtp server and set it to client
- Now my VTP client didn't get the vlans configured on the vtp server, however when I added another vlan on my server, suddenly they were all there

Is there a way to push the configs, like a force update command ?

Comment: post a sh vlan sh vtp status from each switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no manual force update command.  VTP configs are pushed based on the highest current VLAN database revision number.  My suspicion in your initial case is that the revision numbers were equal; thus the client thought it had the correct information.  When you make a VLAN change, the revision number is incremented and sent to clients with a lower revision number.  (show vtp commands will show you the current revision number)

The closest approximation to a 'manual' force is to do just as you did; make a VLAN database change which will force the revision number to increment.

Glad your doing the exercises; for what it's worth VTP isn't recommended to be used in most production environments any more - the risks far outweigh the rewards.

Comment: What's the recommended replacement for VTP?

Comment: Automation tools - eg Cisco Prime LMS, or Cisco DCNM or a 3rd party tool like netmri.  There is no 'in band' replacement to VTP.